# Given size of list, how do I return its factorials as a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, factorial

I'm trying to write a function that accepts the size of a list as an argument and returns a new list with numbers which are essentially the factorials of the list's size. However, I cannot use the factorial() function because it throws "is not defined" error.

Examples of input/output:

> puzzle=[[1,2],[2,2]], size = 2 by 2 (2), all numbers possible new_list=[1,2]
>
> puzzle=[[1],[2],[3]], size = 3 by 3 (3), all numbers possible new_list=[1,2,3]

My current code (not working):

```
def get_valid_numbers(size):
    num=size
    valid_list=[]
    return valid_list.append(num*factorial(num-1))
```

I know this isn't correct but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your are trying to accomplish. A factorial is n!, so for example, 4!=4*3*2*1=24. But I don't see anything like that in your question. By the way, factorial is a function in the math package, so you need to use math.factorial instead.

Comment: @DeathByDenim I guess I got confused on what factorial does. Math never was my strong suit. I'm trying to find all possible numbers that can fit. For instance 3 gives (1,2,3) 2 gives (1,2) 5 gives (1,2,3,4,5) etc

Comment: So like `list(range(1,5+1))` for 5?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
def get_valid_num(size):
    valid_list = list(range(1, size + 1))
    return valid_list
print("All numbers possible: ", get_valid_num(5))
```

Please note that this code does not output factorials but a list of consecutive integers bounded by the size argument (+ 1 as the range() function end value is not inclusive).

If, however, you do want to create lists and populate them with factorials of n-size, you might want to implement this as follows

```
def factorial(size):
    if size <= 2:
        return size
    else:
        size = size * factorial(size - 1)
    return size

# This time you build a list of 120 elements (5! = 120)
def get_valid_num(size):
    valid_list = list(range(1, factorial(size) + 1))
    return valid_list

print("All numbers possible: ", get_valid_num(5))
```

Finally, you might want to create a list with calculated factorials for each element.

```
def factorial(size):
    if size <= 2:
        return size
    else:
        size = size * factorial(size - 1)
    return size

# Populate the list with the value of each factored element
def get_valid_num(size):
    valid_list = list(range(1, size + 1))
    factorials = [factorial(item) for item in valid_list]
    return factorials

print("All numbers possible: ", get_valid_num(5))
```